# CSTR reaction cooling jacket - Transfer Functions

Tags: reaction-control

I have a CSTR where an irreversible exothermic liquid reaction takes place. Coolant is flowing in the jacket of the tank to regulate the temperature of the fluid in the reactor and control in this way the concentration of component A. The cooling jacket stays at a uniform temperature. An on-line infrared spectrometer with no lag is the sensor used to measure the concentration of component A. Reaction rate is given by r(t) = k(T(t)) Css.
The goal is to get all transfer functions between the input and output variables.[image: System]

Comment: In a homework question such as yours you must make some attempt at an answer and explain where you are stuck otherwise the question will be closed without anyone providing an answer.

Comment: Thanks, the question is to find the transfer functions correlating input and output variables, and then to design a controller